# Constructing and deconstructing single case discriminated union with units of measure

Tags: functional-programming, f#, domain-driven-design

I have two types:

- DTO for Dirty Transmission Object ;) that is used to deserialise JSON payloads
- Domain that keeps my data consistent and clean within the domain.

I got two functions that translate records from one space to another. I wanted to use units of measure but the solution seems hacky. I wonder what are the other options of implementing this.

```ml
module MyApp.Api.Dto

open System

[<CLIMutable>]
type Feed = 
    {
        volume: decimal
        entryTime: DateTime
    }
```

```ml
module MyApp.Api.Domain

[<Measure>]
type ml

type FeedVolume = private FeedVolume of decimal<ml>

module FeedVolume =

    let value (FeedVolume f) = f

    let create dec = 
        if dec <= 0m<ml> then Error "Volume must not be negative"
        else Ok (Volume dec)


module Feed =
    let toDomain (dto:Dto.Feed) : Result<Feed,string> =
        result {
            let! volume = dto.volume |> FeedVolume.create 
            let! entryTime = dto.entryTime |> EntryTime.create 

            return {
                Volume = volume
                EntryTime = entryTime
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'decimal -> Result<'a,string>'    
but given a
    'decimal<ml> -> Result<FeedVolume,string>'    
The type 'decimal' does not match the type 'decimal<ml>'
```

I've changed the constructor and deconstructor to the following:

```ml
module FeedVolume =

    let value (FeedVolume f) = f / 1.0m<ml>

    let create (dec:decimal) = 
        if dec <= 0m then Error "FeedVolume must not be negative"
        else Ok (FeedVolume (dec * 1.0m<ml>))
```

...but I'm not sure if that's a correct approach

Comment: The question is how to extract the primitive `float` from a `float<ml>`. You can cast: `let value (FeedVolume f) = float f`. There is a lot of other code here and a title but I'm pretty sure they are not relevant to your actual question, unless you are really asking for a code review.

Comment: IMHO, it's better to move the conversion up the call chain as much as possible. So use `dto.volume*1<ml> |> FeedVolume.create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Newtonsoft to deserialize the JSON, I would just put the units of measure right in the DTO definition.  Your `create` function should validate the invariants of the domain, not the units.  If you want to create a validated domain type from a raw primitive, with no units, you should have a separate function like `unsafeCreate` that forces the primitive into the correct units.

Here's an example using Newtonsoft to deserialize JSON with units in the DTOs:

```ml
[<Measure>] type kg
[<Measure>] type ml

type DtoWithUnitsOfMeasure =
    { 
        Volume: decimal<ml>
        Weight: decimal<kg>
    }


[<Test>]
let ``DTOs with units of measure should deserialize into measured values`` () =
    let json = """{ "volume": 3.2348, "weight": 0.682 }"""
    let dto = json |> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DtoWithUnitsOfMeasure>
    dto.Volume |> should equal 3.2348M<ml>
    dto.Weight |> should equal 0.682M<kg>
```

This test passes for me.